# Are there standard style guides for PHP?

Tags: php, coding-style, coding-standards

I've been working in a very small team for PHP development and we've been using an ad-hoc, "Invented Here" style guide. Now that our team and codebase is growing, we would like to use a more broadly-used style guide that would be, if not an official standard, a de facto standards used in many PHP communities. Does such a thing exist as it exists in the C/C++/Java/Javascript/etc. circles ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [PHP Framework Interop Group](http://www.php-fig.org/) has released a series of coding standard recommendations:

- [PSR-0: Autoloading Standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)
- [PSR-1: Basic Coding Standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md)
- [PSR-2: Coding Style Guide](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) (this is what you are looking for)
- [PSR-3: Logger Interface](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md)

FIG's recommendations are far from an official standard, and I wouldn't even consider them a de facto standard, but they are the more coherent set of recommendations for PHP we have.

Other than FIG's recommendations, you should take a look at [Zend Framework's standards](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html), which include [coding style recommendations](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html), and [PEAR's standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php). Personally I tend to favour FIG's recommendations, they are a bit more coherent than every other set of PHP standards I've seen and are more widely adopted.

You should also take a look at [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer). It's a tool that detects violations of a defined (and configurable) set of coding standards and can be easily automated via [Phing](http://www.phing.info/). If you decide to follow FIG's recommendations, you could also use [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer) to rewrite your code to be PSR-1 and PSR-2 compliant (with a pre-commit hook, for example).

Lastly, keep in mind that the main reason for adopting a coding style standard is consistency, you'll never find a set of standards that will make *everyone* in your team happy. It doesn't really matter which set of standards you'll pick, what matters is that you pick one and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are couple of standards used in the PHP world. Two of them deserve special recomendation.

The PEAR standard, which should be used by all PEAR packages:
http://pear.php.net/manual/nl/standards.php

and the PSR standard, which is supported by some big PHP groups like Symfony, PEAR(again), Drupal, Joomla etc.
https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards

Answer (score 0):

The official PHP Coding Standard can be found in the root of their project:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/CODING_STANDARDS

**UPDATE:** Because people are already starting to down vote my answer. Be sure to actually read the above file. It contains the coding standards for the C part of PHP and for userland code. Specifically lines [136 to 166](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/CODING_STANDARDS#L136-L166) are of interest. Of course the rest is also interesting.

**TL;DR** Build your standard on top of the PHP standard and it looks exactly as the language (from a userland view) does.

Comment: +1 you deserve.

Comment: The link to CODING_STANDARDS no longer exists.